# How to expand dx-treeview at new item?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, expand, devextreme

I have a *CRUD AngularJS* application with *Categories* and *Phones*. I'm trying to expand *dx-treeview* to the new added item.

[image]

After clicking *Save* button it redirects to the new item page:

[image]

I would like to know how to expand *dx-treeview* to the new item.

Comment: What have you already tried? You can use the [expandItem](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Methods/?version=15_2#expandItemitemElement) method or set the [expanded](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Default_Item_Template/?version=15_2#expanded) item field as `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i finded in documentation it too, but i haven't ideas how i can use it in my app.

Comment: When the new page is loaded just call the `expandItem` method with the item id param. See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/80ddt95W0qrTMHmWAkjW?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, it works) You help me so much. Please, copy-paste you comment to Answer i will mark it like a resolve.

Comment: You are welcome! 'Please, copy-paste you comment to Answer' - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, when the new page is loaded just call the [expandItem](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Methods/?version=15_2#expandItemitemElement) method with the item id param.

```
$("#tree-view").dxTreeView("instance").expandItem(/* item id */);
```

See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/80ddt95W0qrTMHmWAkjW?p=preview).